# How to convert LDAP "whenCreated" attribute timestamp 20150527135501.0Z to timestamp in PHP?

Tags: php, ldap, timestamp

How to convert LDAP "whenCreated" attribute timestamp 20150527135501.0Z to timestamp in PHP.

```
$justthese = array("displayname","department" , "title","samaccountname", "mail", "whenCreated"); 

$result = ldap_search($ldap,$dn , $filter ,$justthese) or die ("Search failed");
 $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
print_r ($info);
for ($i=0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++) { 
echo "Name: ".$info[$i]["displayname"][0]."<br>\n"; 
echo "Department: ".$info[$i]["department"][0]."<br>\n"; 
echo "Created: ".$info[$i]["whenCreated"][0]."<br>\n"; 
}
```

I get display name for the user and the department.But i dont get whencreated timestamp. In my print_r ($info);

i get `20150527135501.0Z` as the timestamp.How can i print this timestamp in PHP ?

Comment: Just to clarify, is the issue that the attribute is blank when you try to echo it, or is the issue that you want a human readable format for the timestamp (or some other format such as a unix timestamp)?

Comment: actually both when i try to do print_r ($info); then i can see whencreated date in .OZ format but its not printing in {echo "Created: ".$info[$i]["whenCreated"][0]."<br>\n";

Comment: My thought was probably its the time stamp.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely with the case of the attribute as it is returned from LDAP. Instead try:

```
echo "Created: ".$info[$i]["whencreated"][0]."<br>\n";
```

If that still doesn't do it, I'd need to see the structure of the `$info` array from a `var_dump`.

To get an actual `\DateTime` object, which you can then format in any way you want, you could do:

```
    preg_match("/^(\d+).?0?(([+-]\d\d)(\d\d)|Z)$/i", $info[$i]["whencreated"][0], $matches);
    if (!isset($matches[1]) || !isset($matches[2])) {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Invalid timestamp encountered: %s', $info[$i]["whencreated"][0]));
    }
    $tz = (strtoupper($matches[2]) == 'Z') ? 'UTC' : $matches[3].':'.$matches[4];
    $date = new \DateTime($matches[1], new \DateTimeZone($tz));

    // Now print it in any format you like
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

It would probably be best to turn the above into a function.

Comment: The first line worked itself.Thank you Chad. Appreciate it my friend.

Comment: No problem @Dev ! Glad this solved the problem. Don't forget to click the check-mark on the left to accept it as the answer (: